# How to increase the size of Action Sheets

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm trying to add two UIPickerView's to an ActionSheet that appears on a button press.

The action sheet shows, but it's WAY too small,

NOTE: I'm also using Cocos2d. I don't know if that restricts anything or not.

[image: Example of my ActionSheet]

As you can see, the ActionSheet is just way too small. You can't see anything in the picker view except maybe the first few letters when I scroll.

I have tried

```
 [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 500)];
```

and

```
 [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 500)];
```

Showing Code:

```
[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 500)];
```

What else can I do? Should be I be using something besides ActionSheets maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put your code after `[actionSheet show...]`

Comment: What about using `UIPopoverController`?

Comment: @Nekto I'll try to find an example of it. Right now I'm trying to use a UIView and simply adding it using addSubview.

Comment: If you are designing app only for ipad it is much easier to use `UIPopoverController`

Comment: You really don't show us enough code to accurately help. You should show the code where you create the problematic pickerView; where the problems would logically originate. Not just the code you've written to try to fix it.

Comment: @Nekto I successfully made my popover with two picker views using UIPopoverController. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found in comments the most convenient way to display different kind of custom information in popup view on iPad is by using `UIPopoverController` class rather then trying customizing `UIActionSheet`.

> The `UIPopoverController` class is used to manage the presentation of content in a popover. You use popovers to present information temporarily but *in a way that does not take over the entire screen* like a modal view does. The popover content is layered on top of your existing content in a special type of window. The popover remains visible until the user taps outside of the popover window or you explicitly dismiss it. Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)